# How to select rows from a series based on values or condition, dynamically?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a series produced dynamically, say - `df['col1'].value_counts()`. I can save this as a series `s` and then select rows from the series, for e.g., -

```
s = df['col1'].value_counts()
s_selected = s[s==20]
```

However I would like to achieve the same dynamically, something like - `df['col1'].value_counts().some_function(filtering_condition)`

Dataframe has an API like this - `df.query()`

How to do the same for Series.

Comment: Why don't you wanna filter directly? @Anirban

Comment: `s.loc[some_function(s)]`

Comment: Also this isn't a dupe of the linked question. They are just similar XY questions asked by newbies who don't know any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Series.where` chained with `dropna`

```
s.where(lambda x: x == 20).dropna()
```

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry could not come up with this use of `dropna()` in conjunction with `where()`. That helped.

Comment: This is an open environment to learn. Don't be sorry :) @AnirbanChakraborty